# Move the BitMap image in OnMouseMove of a control

Tags: winforms, mouseevent

I am new to Windows Forms, I have a Bitmap image and i need to move my Bitmap image when the mouse is move, without adding the Bitmap into PictureBox.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Farjana

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using GDI+ libraries.You can do it using onpaint function just like win32 api.I am not an expert but hope clue works...example clue..

```
Bitmap bmp=new Bitmap("pic.jpg");
e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp,150,150);
```

After showing bitmap you can move it in client area by adding more coding.